# AD Authentication with Web Service

Tags: authentication, service

I am trying to develop a web service which will be consumed by various clients on different platforms. I want to authenticate this web service such that the users who call my web service should be authenticated based on NT account they are logged in. My Web service will be hosted in the same domain as my users are, ie my company domain. Any help?

Comment: I want to pass the users AD default credentials to the web service. I know it can be done as:

localhost.Service1 myProxy = new localhost.Service1();
myProxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

But as i said, my clients can be non windows clients too. How can they pass those credentials to my web service so that I can authenticate them against the AD with PrincipalPermission or IsInRole..?

Comment: why don't you check into WCF - it's the current and future technology, and lots of problem cases with "Old-style" ASMX webservices are much easier to deal with in WCF - check out the WCF Developer Center on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf